# SQL update order in relation ship based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder how to update order in this table for many-to-many relationship using SQL based on PostsId.
So my table now looks like:

*I'm using SQL Server*

[image]

|  | BlogsId | PostsId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 0 |

but I want to update Order using SQL to this:

|  | BlogsId | PostsId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2 |

So for example: Blog with Id 3 is the first blog in Post with Id 2, Blog with Id 4 is the second Blog in Post with Id 2 and etc...

I've tried this:

```
DECLARE @myVar int
SET @myVar = 0
UPDATE [dbo].[BlogPost]
SET @myVar = [Order] = @myVar + 1
```

but then I got this:

|  | BlogsId | PostsId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 6 |

So, I think I should do something in WHERE part (with Distinct maybe) but I don't know exactly what. I could write something in C# to do what I want but I don't know how to write something like this in SQL.

Comment: What's expected to happen when someone later deletes the row (4. 2, 4)?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: When someone deletes a row from the table I will manually execute the same query for re-ordering

Comment: Ok, I will try to re-organize my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physically maintaining an order or sequence of rows is rarely a good idea and can lead to data inconsistencies and other unforseen issues.

You would be better off creating a *view* that provides the additional *Order* column which you can do using `row_number()`

```
Create view BlogPosts as
select *,
    Row_Number() over(partition by PostsId order by BlogsId) as [Order]
from blogpost;
```

If you really want to update an actual column in the table you could use a *CTE*

```
with b as (
    select *,
        Row_Number() over(partition by PostsId order by BlogsId) as seq
    from blogpost
)
update b
set [Order] = seq;
```

Comment: Hi Stu, thank you for your help, it works like a charm :) I get it that manually executing scripts is a bad practice. I wrote my c# code around this so the code will handle add, update and delete in right way (when order is set), so I will need to execute this script manually only if someone do something wrong directly in database. And I think that I will try to learn more about SQL and maybe write some triggers and procedures to relax my code. I will take your advice in consideration! Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can update from a calculated row_number.

> ```
> update t 
> set [Order] = rn
> from (
>   select BlogsId, PostsId, [Order]
>   , rn = row_number() over (partition by PostsId order by BlogsId asc)
>   from BlogPost
> ) t
> where ([Order] is null or [Order]!=rn);
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from BlogPost
> order by BlogsId, PostsId
> ```

| BlogsId | PostsId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=753016a8ad73a6d0ba1df655eb17a09e)*